# How to enforce secure binary properties for Android APK in Android Studio?

Tags: android, security, flutter

I ran my APK for an Android project through a security scan and a vulnerability is reported as "ELF binaries do not enforce secure binary properties". I wish to correct this problem by using the compiler option -fstack-protector-all as per the recommendation in the report but it is not being enforced as it fails the scan again. 
I do not know how to manually check if this protection is being added  and I am not sure if I am adding it correctly to build.gradle

Using Android Studio 3.4.2, I have added -fstack-protector-all in build.gradle as shown

```
defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
        cppFlags "-fstack-protector-all"
            }
        }
}
```

and also

```
defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
        arguments "-fstack-protector-all"
            }
        }
}
```

When I build the APK after using the above the same vulnerability is reported when I run the scan again.